# moving Android HIDL to vendor directory and permission issue

Tags: android, android-source, hal

I have written an Android HIDL module at hardware/interfaces/. It has two problems:
1) I create a C++ app at device/goldfish/. This app can find my HIDL module and make it run as root. But another HIDL module could load and run my HIDL module ONLY IF I disable permission by "set enforce 0". how to grand other HIDL permission to use my HIDL module?

2) after I moved my HIDL to vendor directory, code can not be compiled with error:"violates neverallow dir:vendor/ *dir:device/* Vndk.Enabled=true -Vendor=true which is restricted because the VNDK can never contain a library that is device dependent." My Module has no device dependency at all. What went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I use "android.hardware" prefix as my HIDL. After changed to "vendor.myhidle" prefix, the second problem is gone. I will report if 1st one is still there.

Comment: Had you configured SE Policies properly? Are you still looking for an answer?